# How to replace missing values with values from another variable in R? Object DF not found

Tags: r

I have a data set with several missing values in "Actual" variable. Where "Actual" is missing, I'd like to replace with the value from the "Screener" variable. I have done some searching but all solutions give me a 'DF' not found error. Such as the one below. the data is imported from csv.

```
> DF <- transform(DF, ActualRecoded = ifelse(!is.na(Actual.Level),Actual.Level, Screener.Level))
Error in transform(DF, ActualRecoded = ifelse(!is.na(Actual.Level),  : 
 object 'DF' not found
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
Screener.Level  Actual.Level
High    
High            High
Low 
Low 
Medium 
Medium  
Medium  
High    
High            High
Medium          Medium
Medium  
Medium  
Medium          High
Low             Low
Medium  
Medium          High
High            High
```

Comment: Please check if you have an object `DF` or else the code would have worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you have not define your dataframe DF. I'll assume your DF has columns "Screener.Level" and "Actual.Level" and you want to replace NAs in "Actual.Level" column with the values in "Screener.Level" columns. You can simply do this:

```
DF$Screener.Level = as.character(DF$Screener.Level)
DF$Actual.Level = as.character(DF$Actual.Level)

DF$Actual.Level = ifelse(!(is.na(DF$Actual.Level)), DF$Actual.Level,DF$Screener.Level)
```